# Вопрос по canvas

Tags: canvas, javascript, html5

Здравствуйте!

Решил заняться обучением фишками html5, появился вопрос по canvas, решение нагуглиить не смог.

Вопрос в чем: допустим, у меня есть игровое поле с разными цветами (например, шахматная доска, или там полосатое поле). Есть фигура, скажем, круг. Если я захочу перемещать круг по этому полю, то мне придется же сначала очистить его и нарисовать с другими x и y. НО!!! Поле, нарисованое мной, тогда затирается. То есть на шахматной доске на черном поле стоит фигура, при перемещении на черном поле остается эта "очищенная зона". И вообще если зацепит, то остается след...
Я не пойму или, наверное, не знаю приема, как не затирать уже нарисованные элементы.

Comment: @u_owl, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 2):

Приёма, позволяющего не затирать уже нарисованные элементы на канвасе при перемещении других элементов, не существует. В отличие от Flash, где вы оперируете объектами, канвас - это просто холст, на котором можно перекрашивать пиксели в нужные цвета. После отрисовки на канвасе пропадает само понятие объекта (круг, квадрат), остаётся только группа перекрашенных пикселей, никак не связанных с исходным объектом. При изменении положения, размера или цвета любого объекта, нарисованного на канвасе, необходимо перерисовать весь канвас или участок, затронутый изменениями. Второй способ достаточно сложен и не имеет серьёзных преимуществ перед первым, поэтому обычно используют первый.

Comment: Добавлю: копирование канвасов производится без особых проблем, поэтому можно физически разделить сцену на несколько скрытых канвасов и рендерить последовательным наложением на одном финальном.

Answer (score 1):

Canvas является элементом для рисования с низкоуровневыми функциями. Если вы что-то рисуете на нем, то управлять нарисованным содержимым нельзя. Обычно приходится все затирать и выводить заново. В этом случае очень помогает ООП и объектный подход.

Для примера, как организовать работу более удобно: [на jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1pw48cL6/)

Код:

```
HTML
<canvas id="canvas" width="300px" height="300px"></canvas>

CSS
canvas{
    outline:1px solid black;
}

JavaScript
canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
context = canvas.getContext("2d");

function clear(){
    context.beginPath();
    context.fillStyle = "#000000";
    context.fillRect(0,0,300,300);
    context.closePath();
}

function Field(canvasApi){
    this.width = 300;
    this.height = 300;
    this.lineX = 8;
    this.lineY = 8;
    this.canvas = canvasApi;
    this.render = function(){
        this.canvas.beginPath();
        for(var i=0;i<this.lineX;i++){
            for(var j=0;j<this.lineX;j++){
                var flag,
                    rectX = (this.width / this.lineX) * j,
                    rectW = this.width / this.lineX,
                    rectY = (this.height / this.lineY) * i,
                    rectH = this.height / this.lineY;

                if(i % 2) flag = (j+1) % 2; 
                    else flag = j % 2;    
                if(flag) this.canvas.fillStyle = "#ffffff";
                    else this.canvas.fillStyle = "#000000";

                this.canvas.fillRect(rectX,rectY,rectW,rectH);
            }
        }
        this.canvas.closePath();
    }
}

function Draught(canvasApi){
    this.canvas = canvasApi;
    this.x = 17;
    this.y = 17;
    this.render = function(){
        this.canvas.beginPath();
        this.canvas.lineWidth = 15;
        this.canvas.strokeStyle = "#00ff00";

        this.canvas.arc(this.x, this.y, 5, 0, Math.PI*2, false);
        this.canvas.stroke();
        this.canvas.closePath();
    }
}

function startDraw(){
    clear();
    field.render();
    draught.render();
}

field = new Field(context);
draught = new Draught(context);

startDraw();
draught.x = 170;
draught.y = 17;
startDraw();
```